# One Association between 3 models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an association between 3 models where 1 of the models has an association with the other 2 but they have no association with each other. I thought I was one the right track and can create data for the 2 models (breweries and restaurants) but cannot get the third model(beers) to correctly save when used in localhost and will not associate with any other models.

The models are

```
class Beer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brewery
  belongs_to :restaurant
  validates :brewery, presence: true
  validates :restaurant, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Brewery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :beers
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :beers
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

I also get an error whenever I try to create a new beer through the local host

[image: Error Message]
This is referring to the beers_controllers method.

```
def create
   @brewery = Brewery.find(params[:brewery_id])
   @beer = @brewery.beers.create(beer_params)
   redirect_to @beer
 end
```

I've tried everything I can think of to no avail and am worried it's just a syntax error that I'm over looking. Would love any advice.

Comment: Show us the form for a beer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because params[:brewery_id] is nil.  Without further information I can only guess but I am thinking that you don't want a beer to belong to both brewery and restaurant.  Doing so would require that a beer has both a brewery and a restaurant every time.  You probably want something more like  a beer has_many beer_venues.  A beer has many venues through beer_venues.  A venue has many beer_venues.  and a venue has many beers through beer_venues.  Then You can use single table inheritance on your venues class to give a type column that is either restaurant or brewery.

Comment: I think Beer ought to be a polymorphic association

Comment: Venue as beerable?  I could see that too.

Comment: Great. I'll give this a shot. Thank you.